# Remove double quotes from array in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have an array as

`col_names = ['"col1"', '"col2"', '"col3"']`

I want to remove double quotes from the above using python. So the output should be as

`col_names = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']`

I tried using below but doesn't work. Can you please advise.

```
for i in col_names: 
    i.strip('"')
    print(i)

for i in col_names: 
    i.replace('"','')
    print(i)
```

Comment: `i.replace` creates **a new object**, which *isn't* the one in the list. Try `[ast.literal_eval(name) for name in col_names]`, so it doesn't break on things that also *contain* quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
col_names = [x[1:-1] for x in col_names]
print(col_names)
```

Output

```
['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
```

Basically, we are taking the substring of every string starting at the second index (1) and ending one before the last index (-1). This way, we omit first and last double quotes(`"`).